# "many a time" means "many times"?

Tags: grammar, phrase-usage

> I never saw anyone work as hard as he did, **many a time** I saw him on the weekends working to his highest standards to give the best research he could give.

From the context, I understand **many a time** equals **many times**. My question is when we can use this structure. Can we, for example, say *many a person* in place of *many people*?

A link explaining this structure will be appreciated.

Comment: Many a time = on many different occasions/often.  It is a somewhat "folksy" manner. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=(many+a+time)&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28many%20a%20time%29%3B%2Cc0  and https://books.google.com/books?id=sIBBAQAAIAAJ&pg=PA33&dq=%22many+a+time%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=A4cDVbTcJo7msATqo4K4AQ&ved=0CDsQ6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=%22many%20a%20time%22&f=false

Comment: reminds me of a family anecdote - my aunt, when she was young [1950's] on arriving home late one night [probably 'late' == after 10pm in those days] was asked by her mother, "Young lady, have you seen that clock?" - to which she replied, "Yes, many a time."

Comment: To my native ear, "many a time" doesn't seem like something that you would normally say (and doesn't *sound* like it's correct grammar, even though it might be correct). I've never heard anyone say it

Comment: @Jojodmo - it's perfectly good English, just antiquated. It's actually quite common in Northern BrE - as are many other antiquated forms.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the 2002 *CGEL*, the usage of the expression ***"many a time"*** is fine and standard English.

But if you use a different count singular noun than "time" in that expression, such as in *"many a person"*, then you might risk having that expression seen as being somewhat formal or archaic.

In the 2002 *CGEL*, page 394:

> ***Many*** in combination with ***a***
>
> *Many* combines with *a* to form two kinds of complex determinative:
>
> [66]
>
> - i. *[**Many a** man] has been moved to tears by this sight.*
> - ii. *[**A great many** complaints] had been received.*
>
> *Many a* is syntactically inert: nothing can intervene between *many* and *a*, and *many* cannot even be replaced in this position by its antonym *few*. Like *a*, *many a* always functions as determiner. It is found in proverbs such as *There's **many a slip** twixt cup and lip*, and in the frequency adjunct *many a time*, but is elsewhere somewhat formal or archaic. The *many* component indicates a large number, but the *a* has an individuating and distributive effect requiring a count singular head.
>
> *Great* in *a great many* can be replaced by *good*, but one or other of these adjectives is required; for the rest, these expressions are syntactically comparable to *a few*. They function as determiner or fused determiner-head (simple or partitive).

---

NOTE: The 2002 *CGEL* is the 2002 reference grammar by Huddleston and Pullum (et al.), *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language*.

Comment: +1 But, there is actually one word that can appear between *many* and *a* in that construction ...

Comment: @Araucaria And that one word is?

Comment: That word, arguably, is "*many*" ;) [which is part of the argument that *many* is an adjective ...]

Comment: @Araucaria Wait! Do you mean something like: *"There's many [many a] slip twixt cup and lip."* :D -- (EDIT: And I'm not seeing any argument for considering either "many" as being an adjective.)

Comment: Well, your prototypical determinative is not stackable. "*Give me a a slice of bread. I want some some beer. I'll have that, that book. I found the the pen*"

Comment: @Araucaria Hmm, it seems you might have something there, where something like *"many many a time"* might be falling in between the cracks in CGEL's framework. It seems that adjectives do intensificatory repetition/tautology, and the syntactically inert determinative "many a" can only function as a determiner. So, that does seem to pose as a hiccup. :)

Comment: Great! And what about its corresponding verb? Should I say *Many a person are waiting for you* or *Many a person is waiting ...*? considering the meaning the former and considering  grammar rules the latter sounds better.

Comment: @Juya I've added the rest of the CGEL info, which includes: [66.i] _"Many a man has been moved to tears by this sight"_, and it uses a singular verb ("has") which agrees with the singular noun ("man") in the subject. :)

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can say *many a person* instead of *many persons*; you can use "*many a*" for a large number of (many) people or things.

The only difference is that "*many*" is more common in use, whereas the phrase "*many a*" is formal, old-fashioned, or literary. Many is used with a plural noun and verb, whereas "many a" is used with a singular noun and verb.

> Many persons don't come to this restaurant. 
> Many a person doesn't come to this restaurant.

Comment: Yes, I remember that I had read somewhere in Swan about this. +1 :)

Comment: Between "Many persons don't come to this restaurant" and "Not many people come to this restaurant", I think I prefer the latter.

Comment: @DamkerngT. I agree your sentence sounds better.