# What is the correct use of 'Many a'?

Tags: grammar, formal-language

Which of the following sentences is correct?

> "Many a **girls** was appearing in the examination."
>
> "Many a **girl** was appearing in the examination."

Comment: See [this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/4904/many-a-year-vs-many-years), and [this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/52731/many-a-time-means-many-times) and [this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/67294/why-is-many-a-man-singular-while-many-men-plural) and [so on](https://ell.stackexchange.com/search?q=Many+a) and so on....

Answer (score 3):

*Many a girl* or the second option is correct. *Many a* always uses a singular noun and is more formal than the word *many*. It is not much common and is used usually in newspapers and famous writings. *Many a* is used to indicate a large number of something.

Answer (score 2):

### Many a/an...

The quick answer to the question is "Many a girl" is correct, and "Many a girls" is incorrect.

> The fixed expression *many a/an...* is more formal than the single word *many*, and it is much less common. *Many a/an...* is used mainly in literary writing and newspapers. Like the adjective and pronoun *many*, *many a/an...* is used **to indicate a large number of something**. However, **it takes a singular noun**, which can be followed by a singular verb.
>
> Here are some examples:
>
> 1. It remained a mystery for many a year.  [=for many years]
> 2. I've been there many a time.  [=many times]
> 3. Many a politician has promised to make changes. [=many politicians have]

Source: [Merrian-Webster Learner's Dictionary](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/qa/the-difference-between-many-and-many-a).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to say many a x, you need to use a singular noun. So many a girl would be correct. However, if you want, you could say many girls appeared / are appearing instead. if you take out the "a / an", many becomes plural and you can then use plural nouns like "girls" or "cars".

Answer (score 1):

The second sentence is correct.

> Many a girl was appearing in the examination.

"Many a" is always followed by a singular noun/ pronoun/ verb.