# I've seen many [ a shooting star / shooting stars ] lately

Tags: indefinite-article

Is the former like there were a few days where a single shooting star appeared? And is the latter like there were a few days where one or more than one shooting stars appeared?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["many a time" means "many times"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/52731/many-a-time-means-many-times) Both mean the same thing with slightly different nuances. As for the number of days, there is not enough context.

Comment: @niamulbengali The answers from your link say "many a time = many times", so then if I see 3 shooting stars three days in a row (9 in total), would I still be able to say it like "I've seen many a shooting star lately"?

Comment: *Many a <singular noun>* means *many <plural noun>*. Let us consider anything more than five shooting stars many shooting stars. Then if you have recently seen nine, on three separate days, you would say, *I have seen many a shooting star lately* and it would be grammatical as well as semantically correct. However, "lately" refers to recent times. So if you said this a year later, it might be incorrect. Your original sentences say nothing in particular about the distribution of the sightings. You should say *I've seen many a star/meteor shower lately* to be more precise about different days.

Comment: It would be _much_ more idiomatic to say "I've seen many" or "a lot of shooting stars lately."  As the comments on the other question say, _many a_ is a rather old-fashioned usage - _many a time_ is probably the most common expression. You might say "I've seen many a shooting star" if you were thinking back over the times you had seen one in your whole life.